# How to show only corresponding div of nav-tag?

Tags: jquery

```
var topRange      = 200,  // measure from the top of the viewport to X pixels down
 edgeMargin    = 20,   // margin above the top or margin from the end of the page
 animationTime = 1200, // time in milliseconds
 contentTop = [];
 $(document).ready(function(){ 
 $('html,body').bind('scroll mousedown DOMMouseScroll mousewheel keyup',       function(e){
if ( e.which > 0 || e.type == 'mousedown' || e.type == 'mousewheel' ){
$('html,body').stop();
}
})

// Set up content an array of locations
$('#sidemenu').find('a').each(function(){
contentTop.push( $( $(this).attr('href') ).offset().top );
 })

// Animate menu scroll to content
$('#sidemenu').find('a').click(function(){
var sel = this,
   newTop = Math.min( contentTop[ $('#sidemenu a').index( $(this) ) ],   $(document).height() - $(window).height() ); // get content top or top position if at the document bottom
   $('html,body').stop().animate({ 'scrollTop' : newTop }, animationTime,    function(){
   window.location.hash = $(sel).attr('href');
    });
   return false;
    }  )


   $(window).scroll(function(){
   var winTop = $(window).scrollTop(),
   bodyHt = $(document).height(),
   vpHt = $(window).height() + edgeMargin;  // viewport height + margin
   $.each( contentTop, function(i,loc){
   if ( ( loc > winTop - edgeMargin && ( loc < winTop + topRange || (  winTop + vpHt ) >= bodyHt ) ) ){
   $('#sidemenu li')
  .removeClass('selected')
  .eq(i).addClass('selected');
   }
   })
   })

   })
```

http://jsfiddle.net/m2zQE/

In this fiddle I want that only the corresponding div will be visible not other and when we scroll then next will be shown. So it will work like when we scroll on screen next tab is active and corresponding comes into viewport, no scroll is there and also no visibility of other div.

How can I do that, I have to integrate this part in a full page website where 1-10 features are there when user scroll one by one he can see the features.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rpyLfv04/  (it's working fine on click, yo need to apply it on your page.). any how scroll will come for sure in a small window

Comment: i added this on my page see the fourth section https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eRbKyN

Comment: can you explain what is not working?

Comment: ohk will check that .. thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: If you check fourth section you will see that side bar is not fixed and also other divs are visible I just want that sidebar will be fixed and on scroll div keep on changing according to the tab.. rest I am also trying to change the container